# CSS shapes: How do I fix my semi-circle code?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert a UI design to HTML/CSS and I have faced an issue with shapes using CSS I made an example but it is not what I was expected.

How do I achieve the same result in the picture using CSS?

**CSS Code:**

```
.semi-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-80%, -100%);
    z-index: -1;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    background-color: var(--bs-danger);
    border-radius: 100% 0% 100% 0% / 100% 100% 0% 0%;
}
```

**Live Example:** https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/NWabvad

**The result that I want to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more of what your actual issue is?

Comment: you can see the different between my example and result

Comment: Not really, your code is creating the shape, so what's the _actual_ issue?

Comment: my shape is not equal to expected result

Comment: Okay, so your code is fine then? Just tweak the values until you get the shape you want, easy

Answer (score 0):

I made a container to keep a semi-circle inside that would help to move that circle around

```
.semi-circle-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-75%, -100%);
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 15rem;
}

.semi-circle {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    background-color: var(--bs-danger);
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

You can verify with my code here too

https://jsfiddle.net/3ks54L0n/

The screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I moved `semi-circle` to the header tag. Then I set `position: absolute` with the needed value(the half of its height) and `z-index: 1`. I specified changing in code:

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1045;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 270px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--bs-white);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

header {
  position: relative; /*here*/
}

#content {
  margin-left: 270px;
  padding: 0 5rem;
}

.semi-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8rem; /*here*/
  left: 0; /*here*/
  z-index: 1; /*here*/
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  background-image: url("https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg"); /*here*/
  background-size: 100% 100%; /*here*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /*here*/
  border-radius: 50%; /*here*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <aside id="sidebar"></aside>
  <div id="content">
    <header class="bg-primary text-white p-5 mb-4">
      <h5>Header</h5>
      <div class="semi-circle"></div> <!--here-->
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="container bg-warning p-5 rounded-3 shadow">
        <h1 class="mb-3">What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
        <p class="lead mb-0">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="position-relative py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 text-center text-lg-start mb-lg-0 mb-3">
            <p>
              Designed with love by &copy;
              <a href="" class="link-secondary fw-bold">name</a>
              <script>
                new Date().getFullYear() > document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
              </script>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul class="list-unstyled hstack gap-5 justify-content-lg-end justify-content-center font-poppins">
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Terms &amp; Condition</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

See: https://codepen.io/ebrahimi73/pen/bGYZepE